# Drop WLAN/local wifi connections to router management?

Tags: networking, firewall, port, mikrotik-routeros

RouterOS v6.48.6 (long-term)

I've set a rule: Protocol (6) tcp; dst. port 8291; In. interface list WAN.

**UPDATE START**.

Due to comments, I understand that WAN was not correct.  I am a beginner in terms of networking.  What I am trying to accomplish is to prevent Wi-fi users from accessing the management page.

**UPDATE END**.

I feel like this should work because don't wifi devices connect on tcp?  And isn't the router-management port 8291?  Yet after setting this rule and applying the changes, I am able to access router management from a wifi-connected device.

I'd like to block all router management via wifi with the exception of one mac address.  Please, tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it from Firewall Rules.

### Update 2: workaround

I am still interested in learning how to accomplish this, but a workaround is more effective.

Go Webfig, ip>firewall>Address lists.

Add two lists:

(1) the list of all the ip addresses of the devices that are allowed to connect to the management interface in `192.168.88.251-192.168.88.253` for example.

(2) the list of all the ip addresses of the mikrotik routers tha they are allowed to access: `192.168.88.1-192.168.88.3` for example.

Go to Webfig, ip>firewall>Add New.  Use these rules:

- Chain: input.
- Protocol: 6 (tcp).
- Dst. port: 21,22,23,80,8291
- Src. address list: the list of devices you made above.  Tic the box (means NOT).
- Dst. address list: the list of routers you made above.
- Action: drop.
- Comment: give a good description (i.e., Wolfpack'08 was here: drop all connections to router admin interface not from the support-device ip-addresses).

Comment: WiFi (or W-LAN) is on the LAN side, not WAN. Be careful to not lock yourself out.

Comment: @mashuptwice Thank you.  I am trying to learn about this stuff by studying CISCO, but I honestly am only like 2 hours up on the course.   I thought WAN was wifi-lan.  I'm sorry.  So, I did set up "input" and my options are LAN, static, WAN, all, none, and dynamic.  I know WAN means wide-area network, now.  How do I --

Comment: There is no such thing as "WiFi-LAN". WiFi is basically a brand name, WLAN is the abbreviation of wireless local area network. [I've never used Mikrotik devices, but this is the first search result for routeros block wifi management access](https://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?t=173090)

Comment: Are you saying that there are three routers whose WAN ports are connected to the LAN ports of another router, and you want to restrict the access from other hosts in this LAN to the three routers? In that case that's an L2 thing. To *actually* restrict such access you'll need the switch part of that main router to have some kind of L2 firewall (it can still be ip-based though, or mac-based, or the best, port-based). (Assuming you can set up the restriction on the three routers themselves.)

Comment: The reason is that within the same broadcast domain, the other hosts does not even need to involve the "router part" of the main router to reach their neighbours. Certainly you can force them to do it that way, but when it comes to security that sort of loses the point. (Assuming the main router is some kind of consumer grade router that comes with 2 Ethernet interfaces, with one attached with a switch to provide the LAN ports).

Comment: @TomYan Thank you.  Sorry--death in the family.  The network map is: modem-router+[eth: printer, pc0, pc1] [wifi: 3x android phone, pc2], sometime guests..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see a possible solution, please read Tom Yan's comment on the question.

I ended up doing a work-around solution where I added a rule such that anything other than a list of addresses (you can build an address list in the ip>firewall>address list tab) is not allowed to point to the list of router ip addresses. You can click the box left of something to mean "not". So not from 192.168.88.250-251 dropped if-to 192.168.88.1. I did read that page (linked above). It's convoluted and doesn't actually describe how to use the management interface. If it does explain how to do this, it's very complicated and not worthwhile--you get a stronger affect with an accept rule